# Angular 2 catch on observable causes an error:

Tags: angular

This is my code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { ICountry } from '../interfaces/country';

@Injectable()
export class RecruiterService {
private _countriesUrl = '/countries.json';


constructor(private http: Http) { }

getCountries(): Observable<ICountry[]> {
    return this.http.get(this._countriesUrl)
        .map((country: Response) => <ICountry[]> country.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

 private handleError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
}
```

The whole of my getCountries method red lines, but as soon as I comment out the catch all the red lines go.

whether I leave the catch line commented out or not. Then in the component where I want to use the method:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { ICountry } from '../services/interfaces/country';
import { RecruiterService } from '../services/recruiter/recruiter.service';

@Component({
selector: 'agent-details',
templateUrl: 'agent-details.component.html',

providers : [RecruiterService]
})
   export class AgentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
   private country: ICountry[] = [];
   private errorMessage: string;

   constructor(private recruiterService : RecruiterService) {

   } 

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.recruiterService.getCountries()
        .subscribe(
        country => this.country = <any>country,
            error => this.errorMessage = error);
   }
}
```

red lines on the **country** => of subscribe

I have found that if I declare my getCountries Method without Observable then all the red lines go:

```
 getCountries()  {
    return this.http.get(this._countriesUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <ICountry[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

So Why cant it be observable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you try wth something like this:

```
 public GetAll = (): Observable<ICountry[]> => {
        return this._http.get(this.actionUrl).map((response: Response) => <ICountry[]>response.json());
    }



    public countries: ICountry[]=[]

    this._dataService
            .GetAll()
            .subscribe(data => this.countries = data,
            error => (response) => {
                //this._toasterService.pop('error', 'Damn', 'Something went wrong...');
            },
            () => {
                //this._toasterService.pop('success', 'Complete', 'Getting all countries complete');

            });
```

hope it helps

Comment: If I take your example : from my original code I just comment out the catch line  and declare my getCountries method as public. All of this code is in file1.ts. In file2.ts where I attempt to call the method it red lines on `data` at the point i'm trying to map to this.countries.

Comment: no because it error's in the file that is trying to use it. I've expanded my original question to show the other file that's making the call. it might make more sense to you.

Comment: I failed to notice the subtle `= ()` after the method declaration. I changed my method signature to your way and it has removed the lines. Can you tell me what doing this means.

Comment: it is call FAT ARROW FUNCTION .. i think it happen cause fat arrow don't miss the scope (this)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this

```
.catch(err => this.handleError(err));
```

Comment: still red lines :(

Answer (score 0):

try below code--

```
this.bbService.getDetails()
      .subscribe((success) => {
        console.log(success);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log('error---',error);
    });
```